# Distance between two elements in an two dimensional array

Tags: arrays

I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle game with program. For this reason i need to find distance between two elements of an two dimensional array.
for example

```
int[][] input = { { 8, 5, 1 }, { 7, 4, 3 }, { 2, 0, 6 } };
```

if i want to move the '8' into the position [2][2], i will need 4 moves(move 2 cells horizontally and 2 vertically) which is the distance from [0][0] to [2][2]. now how can i get this distance?

Comment: Actually, its the distance form [0][0] to [2][2].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from [a1][b1] to [a2][b2] is abs(a1-a2)+abs(b1-b2).